# Is there a grid system in magento 1.9 RWD like the Bootstrap one?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

The bootstrap grid system is really cool, but I can't find something similar in magento 1.9 rwd theme.

Is there anything like that in the new magento rwd theme?

If not, what is the best way to have something similar to bootstrap with the magento rwd theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven´t looked at the new RWD theme but there is some good "boilerplate" themes out there.

https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate Based on Bootstrap 3
https://github.com/zeljkoprsa/waterlee-boilerplate Based on ZURB Foundation 5